# image won't show up opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to display an image *123.jpg* on the screen, the display view did show up but the image didn't and the program exits with status 255

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("123.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    namedWindow("displayWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("displayWindow", image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a problem in the code ?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThCtw.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN7Ve.png)

Comment: The error message is not understandable, can you `std::cout << image.size() << std::endl` before the `namedWindow` to check if the image was loaded properly ?

Comment: @ZdaR I already checked that the image has been loaded successfully using `image.data` and `image.empty()`, `image.size()` returns [512 x 512]

Comment: try omitting the `namedWindow("displayWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);` line

Comment: @ZdaR I already did that too, in this case, even the frame don't show up ! I've also tried to debug the code before posting this and I get a segmentation fault SIGSEGV in the line `imshow("displayWindow", image);`

Comment: Then You should try installing the OpenCV once again after installing `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`, the package which is responsible for `imshow` to work

Comment: are you using debug libraries/dlls in debug build and release libs in release build?

Comment: @Micka yes I configured Code::Blocks to use them

Comment: @ZdaR I reinstalled opencv and now it works, thanks